# Time in specific format Android Java

Tags: java, android, time, format

I would like the time respresented as this  "Thu Jan 01 08:40:38 GMT+01:00 1754"

so i did this :

```
                Date datu = new Date();
                datu.setYear(1754);
                datu.setMonth(0);
                datu.setDate(1);
                DateFormat.format("%tc", datu);

                // DATU = Thu Jan 01 08:40:38 GMT+01:00 3654
                String startTime = datu.toGMTString();
```

now the problem is that i set the year on 1754 in the code. but as I print it out. there is 3654 ?

EDIT:
datu.setYear(1754-1900) can do the trick. but isn't there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd hh:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR,1754);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0); // JAN
c.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(c.getTimeInMillis())));
```

Output

```
Tue Jan 01 05:23:55 GMT+0800 1754
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of the Java API are you using?
I would suggest you use the java.text.SimpleDateFormat and java.util.Calendar instead.
You code would look something like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(1754, 0, 1);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); // <- customize your format
sdf.format(cal.getTime()); // <- get your string
```

The date.toGMTString() method is also deprecated so it's best to avoid it.

Comment: You'll find all the formatting pattern elements here [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that date.SetYear is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). According to the documentation you should use Calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, date.setYear(desired year-1900) fixes the problem. It is noteworthy that the method is deprecated it is better you use the Calendar class which doesnt require subtracting 1900 from the year. A code snippet that will achieve what you are doing using Calendar is giving below:

```
Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);// note that the date object here will be datu according to 
//your code. It could be any object of the Date class
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Hope this helps.

Feel free to mark as answer if it solves your problem.
Good luck!